# How to make two files identical in trunk and branch using TortoiseSVN when changes in both need to be kept?

Tags: java, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have changes in a file from a package in both Trunk and Branch. Some changes are in Trunk. Some changes are in Branch. I need to make both Trunk and Branch identical with all those changes.

**Aim:**

1. Both Trunk and Branch files need to be identical.
2. Changes are present in the file in Trunk and also in Branch. All these changes need to be kept.
3. No change from either Trunk or Branch should be disposed during merging.

**This is the File A in Trunk**:

```
{
    String fromTrunk = "This is a new change commited in Trunk";
    String inTrunkAndBranch = "This is identical both in Trunk and Branch";
}
```

This is the tree structure of File A:

```
SourceCodeTrunk
-->Server
--------->ipAssign.java
--------->routerDispatch.java
--------->FileA.java
```

**This is the File B in Branch:**

```
{
    String inTrunkAndBranch = "This is identical both in Trunk and Branch";
    String fromBranch = "This is a new change committed in Branch";
}
```

This is the tree structure of File A:

```
SourceCodeBranch
-->Server
--------->ipAssign.java
--------->routerDispatch.java
--------->FileB.java
```

After merging operations I want both the files File A(Present in Trunk) and File B(Present in Branch) are the same.

**This is what I want in both Trunk and Branch:**

```
{
    String fromTrunk = "This is a new change commited in Trunk";
    String inTrunkAndBranch = "This is identical both in Trunk and Branch";
    String fromBranch = "This is a new change committed in Branch";
}
```

What sequence of operations in Tortoise SVN will help me achieve this?

**Important:**

1. SourceCodeTrunk and SourceCodeBranch are the Source folders.
2. Server is a Java package.
3. Please note that at the same time any of the files in the Package Server might be needing a similar update. I have picked File A and File B for reference.

Comment: So as a results, you want to keep both files: FileA.java and FileB.java with the same content? Or you just want to keep one file?

Comment: I want both the files to be present in their respective places with changes from both ends. In short, both Trunk and Branch should be identical with the new changes from both Trunk and Branch.

Comment: Well, in trunk I would copy FileA.java and rename it to FileB.java. In branch, copy FileB.java and rename it to FileA.java. So I would have FileA.java and FileB.java in both trunk and branch. Then merge branch to trunk, and after that create new branch based on trunk.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the question. They are named the same.

Comment: Then the answer is even simpler: just merge branch to trunk, and create new branch from there. What's the problem in here?

Comment: @Peska - problem **is** "overlapping chunk" of changes in files, which disallow automatic merge

Comment: So how exactly should I be approaching this with Tortoise SVN?

Comment: You need to merge trunk from branch. After the automatic merge before the commit you need to check if it merged as you want. If not, change it manually and commit. Then, merge the branch from the trunk. And again, before the commit check if the merge done as you want. If no, change it manually and commit.